# How can I update a table based on a plpgsql instruction loop on PostgreSQL 8.3.16?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a problem I not sure how to solve it so far...

I have two tables that are related to each other with a 1 x n relation. I will try to describe the more importants fields below:

Table One - company:id PK,companyname varchar;
Table Two - training: course varchar,companyid bigint FK,id PK;

The problem is: I would like to update the information on course field of the table training because there are many courses with the same name. My idea is use something like

```
for s in 1..n loop 
update training set course = course || s;
end loop;
```

Comment: Version 5.0.0 doesn't exist, the oldest version is Postgres95, the next version was 1.0 and then made a jump to 6.0. But that was in 1995 / 1997, about 20 years ago.

Comment: I edit the title to right version, tks

Comment: Version 8.6 doesn't exist either.... How did you determine the version you're using? Please try this query: SELECT version();

Comment: I used but I write wrong, sorry...Now I will put the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved mine doubt creating this function below:

**CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION**  *changeName()*
**RETURNS VOID AS** 
$$
**DECLARE**
*table1id*  **table1.id%TYPE**;
 
*counter1*  **RECORD**;
*counter2*  **RECORD**;

**BEGIN

FOR** *counter1* **IN SELECT**
 *repeated_column,foreign_keyid*,**COUNT**(*repeated_column*) **AS** *contagem*
 
**FROM**  *table1*  **GROUP BY**  *repeated_column,foreign_keyid* **HAVING 
COUNT**(*repeated_column*) > 1 **LOOP

FOR**  *counter2* **IN** 1..*counter1.contagem* **LOOP 

SELECT id INTO table1id FROM table1 WHERE repeated_column
 IN**(*counter1.repeated_column*) **AND**  *foreign_keyid = counter1.foreign_keyid*;
**UPDATE** *table1*  **SET** *repeated_column = repeated_column || ' (' || counter2 || ')'*  **WHERE** *id = table1id*;
**END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END;**
$$
**LANGUAGE** 'plpgsql'

Comment: Just a side note: the language name is an identifier. Don't quote it. Use `LANGUAGE plpgsql`

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop you can do this with plain SQL:

```
with numbered as (
   select id, 
          row_number() over (order by id) as rn
   from training
)
update training 
   set course = course||n.rn::text
from numbered n
where n.id = training.id;
```

The [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) assigns a number for each row in the `training` table and that number is then used to generate the new course name.

Comment: I got another problem...this version I using doesn't have row_number() over function...I already tryed this approach...

Comment: @JoséAlves Then you are using a version that is no longer maintained (i.e. 8.4 or even older). That's one of the reasons you should always specify your version, **especially** if you are using a completely outdated one.

Comment: @JoséAlves: there is no 5.0 version of Postgres. What exactly does `select version()` show you? (and it's Postgres not Postgre)

Comment: I see...my version is the 8.6, I just saw it.

Comment: @JoséAlves: there is no 8.6 either. What does `select version()` show you?

Comment: haha...Isee..I write wrong, sorry...Now I will put the right one

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE training
SET course = course || num
FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(1, (
                SELECT count(course)
                FROM training
                )) num
    ) t
```